# Apply perspective on images - homography

Tags: c++, opencv, homography

I've a marker and I want to apply an homography transformation to it. For example I have this image with its own frame, what I want to do is to rotate the image around X axis for example.

I can use `warpPerspective` but I need that matrix (homography) for a particular transformation (eg. 30deg / X). How can I generate such a matrix?

[image]

Comment: Rotational homographies rotate about the top-left point. Thus to rotate it about the center, you need to translate the image so that it's center is at (0, 0), then rotate, then translate back. This will give you three homographies. Homographies compose, so you can just multiply the three homographies together if you want to have all of that in one matrix.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds well my question is about how to get that rotation homography transformation so as I can use it in warpPerspective for example!

Comment: Ah, you just need to look up a rigid/Euclidean transform. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Image_transformation).

Answer (score 0):

For a perspective/homography transformation, you can use [`getPerspectiveTransform()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga8c1ae0e3589a9d77fffc962c49b22043). For rotation alone you can use [`getRotationMatrix2D()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gafbbc470ce83812914a70abfb604f4326), this is an affine transform, see need to call [`warpAffine()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983) for that.